# Simplest current limiting method for battery charging

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, lithium-ion, current-limiting

I need to charge 12V car battery (from main battery), but I have to limit current, because power cables are quite thin and I don't want to draw too much power from main system (in case battery is empty). What would be simplest solution (without ineffective linear regulators)? I though about PWM controlled LC circuit, but maybe there are controllers (ICs) made for that? I would like to charge the battery at no more than 3A.

Those cheap chinese converters have current limiting option through potentiometer, but I want something less delicate.

Comment: What batteries are those and what voltages they have?

Comment: regular lead car batteries

Comment: Given your requirements stated (which are in no way sufficient to make a better judgement), a 1 Mohm resistor would likely suffice. Might even get away with something much smaller in value too.

Comment: well a resistor (1 Ohm) would limit the current, but it would also wouldn't be very efficient. I could get ~18W of charging power and ~4W of losses. But it very depends on what is batteries internal resistance.

Comment: +1 on a resistor.

Comment: @RiDi Since you want to minimize losses, then you will need a switcher to do the job. More, since you want to control the output current, it's a transconductance DC to DC buck-boost converter. And these are not "simplest" by anyone's estimation.

Comment: So I guess I'll try the resistor method. By far the simpliest

Comment: Connect a car headlight bulb in series - 55W @ 12V is 4.5A so close enough. Used bulbs like that after rewiring cars so any fatal shorts weren't...

Comment: "(without ineffective linear regulators)"  Actually, linear regulators are very effective.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s see your wish-list:

1. Charge a 12V car battery from the “main battery”. <=> Assumed here the main battery is the battery connected to the car starter engine and alternator.
2. Use of thin cables, to not draw to much power in case “aux” battery is empty.
   Here is a problem, as *thin cables should not be used* to present a high resistance to limit the current. This is wrong and dangerous! More on that later.
3. Simplest solution without inefficient linear regulators. <=> Linear is inefficient, but are simple and can be very robust.
4. Something less delicate than “Chinese converters”.

My thoughts of what you will need:

1. **Charging/equalizing cables** compatible with the maximum current expected to charge the Aux-12V battery. Surely anything of at least of 4 mm^2 or 12AWG, for at least 20A and a couple of meters long, but 6 mm^2 or 10AWG is good up to 30A; and 8AWG goes up to 40A safely, without overheating. And please, **do protect the Positive cable(s) with Fuse(s)** rated accordingly.
2. **Switching device**: For something Robust and Fool-proof, use 12V relays as switching elements; they are more forgiving than bipolar or mosfet transistors. Auxiliary relays can operate 30 to 40A, so you may be ok if you use a current limiting feature (later). You will need two relays, eventually a third one.
3. **Current limiting circuit**: The simplest and a robust solution is to use headlight lamps as power resistors. A more elegant option is to use sensing resistors (0.6~0.7V of voltage drop at max. current) monitored by a driver transistor to control a series-pass power transistor, heatsinked.This is essentially a current limit, but causes a minimum voltage drop of about 1.0V.
4. A **Control circuit**, to measure voltage differential between batteries and absolute voltage in Aux-Batt, and act according to these voltages. For example: (A) If voltage differential is low enough, the current-limit circuit (or lamps) could be bypassed by above Aux-relays, enabling a complete charge and in shorter time. (B) If Aux-Batt voltage is too low, another Aux-relay could disconnect the battery. (C) If Aux-Batt is fully-charged, a third Aux-Relay could disconnect the charging circuit. Hysteresis and interlocking logic could be used to prevent erratic operation of relays.

Finally, I suggest you to check if a dedicated **VSR - Voltage Sensitive Relay** as those used in trucks and motor-homes could solve your needs. I believe it does. Here are two links of different brands - a [VSR only](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BRJRY42) or as a [VSR kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WTAFR5W).
I found also a good reference about **Split Charging Methods** - [here](https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/split-charging.html). See below a typical VSR assembly diagram:
[image]

Let us know what you would prefer to do - use a Split charging system as those VSR-based, or to make and tinker your own system “VSR-like”, where the above list is a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

What about a 2-transistor constant current sink? Use an NPN as the control transistor. If you put in a 0.2 Ohm resistor, the NPN will  choke the pass transistor at about 3-4 A. If current is lower, the pass transistor will be fully on and can be a low resistance N-MOSFET.

This is probably a little bit more efficient than using only a resistor of around 1-2 ohm.

However, I think the 55W, 12 V bulb in series as suggested by @SolarMike is actually a more elegant way to achieve similar behavior. The transistor version allows setting the current limiter more deliberately, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

They sell a ready-made solution: 12 V to 12 V battery charger.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=12+V+to+12+V+battery+charger

Comment: why not? May be the newly invented wheel is rounder. And how do  those devices you have mentioned work?

Comment: the charger you suggested has "Input Voltage 110-240V AC"

Comment: 12V to 12V would be perfect for me, but I did not find anything like that

Comment: They definitely exist. Boats and RV's use them. Here is a victron product that might work for you: https://www.victronenergy.com/dc-dc-converters/orion-tr-smart

Comment: Here are some other useful search terms for the OP: ACR (automatic charging relay). VSR (voltage sensing relay). Battery Combiner.

Comment: @mkeith
Oh my god, do not use relays between batteries to charge a Li-ion battery!!! That's a sure way to fry it. Those Mikey Mouse solutions may have worked so-so for lead acid batteries, but are terrible for Li-ion batteries.

Comment: Not clear to me that the OP is using LiFePO4. ACR's and VSR's are specifically designed for exactly what the OP is trying to do. I don't think I am out of line is suggesting that the OP read up about them.

Comment: You're right: OP didn't say. I apologize for assuming.

Comment: I'll be using LTO batteries.

Comment: Thank you'll need a Li-ion charger, with a CCCV curve.